# I have a problem with the following MySQL query with some logical gates

Tags: mysql

The following query is causing me a few issues. The query below should return two records but for some reason it returns four, with the extra two being records that do not have a customer_id of "420" Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
SELECT * FROM search_record LEFT JOIN customers ON search_record.customer_id = customers.customer_id LEFT JOIN customer_company ON customers.company_id = customer_company.company_id 
WHERE (search_record.customer_id = '420')
AND (search_id like '%165%') 
OR (identity_code LIKE '%165%')
OR status LIKE '%165%'
OR comments LIKE '%165%'
OR county LIKE '%165%'
OR property_address1 LIKE '%165%'
OR property_address2 LIKE '%165%'
OR property_town LIKE '%165%'
OR postcode LIKE '%165%'
OR requester LIKE '%165%'
OR company_name LIKE '%165%'
OR customer_ref LIKE '%165%' 
ORDER BY search_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

AND is higher precedence than OR, so any of your OR ... conditions alone will cause the record to be selected.  Add parentheses around the conditions you want OR'd:

```
SELECT * FROM search_record LEFT JOIN customers ON search_record.customer_id = customers.customer_id LEFT JOIN customer_company ON customers.company_id = customer_company.company_id 
WHERE (search_record.customer_id = '420')
AND (
    search_id like '%165%' 
    OR identity_code LIKE '%165%'
    OR status LIKE '%165%'
    OR comments LIKE '%165%'
    OR county LIKE '%165%'
    OR property_address1 LIKE '%165%'
    OR property_address2 LIKE '%165%'
    OR property_town LIKE '%165%'
    OR postcode LIKE '%165%'
    OR requester LIKE '%165%'
    OR company_name LIKE '%165%'
    OR customer_ref LIKE '%165%' 
)
ORDER BY search_id DESC
```

Comment: Perfect, worked instantly. Thanks for the fast response.